# mysql rows count in php with num_rows() is reliable?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, numbers, rows

I used mysqli_num_rows() in php to count the query rows, then in the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) I read:

> The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved

What do they mean exactly ? When the query is unbuffered and when buffered ?

Thanks.

Comment: Barmar, in that question there is an example of unbuffered. How is the buffered ? So I'd say no, it's not duplicate! Van Tuan answer is ? what ? Im more confused than before...

Answer (score -1):

Example

Return the number of rows in a result set:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Check connection

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
```

Return the number of rows in result set

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
```

Free result set

```
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of whether the buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used?